# compare all row in database

Tags: sql

i have table like below in my sql server i need a query to give me an out put that check all EmpID and where EmpID are equals check EmployeeType where the EmployeeType are equal in that EmpID  give me first row that has min StartAction
and if EmployeeType change in certain EmpID  give me that row too

this is my example table my record are more than 200,000

```
EmpID                Serial      EmpType      SAction
-------------------- ----------- ------------ -----------
10012845             2           5            940705
10012845             3           5            951218
10012845             4           5            960130
10012845             5           5            970419
10012845             6           5            970419
13395353             1           5            921113
13395353             2           5            931116
13395353             3           2            941119
13395353             4           1            951214
13395353             5           1            961713
10013597             1           5            890201
10013597             2           53           921003
10013597             3           53           960320
10013597             4           53           970419
10013597             5           53           970419
```

my desire output

row with **{description} are my desire rows

```
    EmpID                Serial  EmpType       SAction
-------------------- ----------- ------------ -----------
10012845             2           5            940705** same empid and first EmpType and min SAction
10012845             3           5            951218
10012845             4           5            960130
10012845             5           5            970419
10012845             6           5            970419
13395353             1           5            921113** same empid and first EmpType and min SAction
13395353             2           5            931116
13395353             3           2            941119**same empid and different EmpType and min SAction
13395353             4           1            951214**same empid and different EmpType and min SAction
13395353             5           1            961713
10013597             1           5            890201**same empid and first EmpType and min SAction 
10013597             2           53           921003**same empid and different EmpType and min SAction
10013597             3           53           960320
10013597             4           53           970419
10013597             5           53           970419
```

more simple desire output

```
    EmpID                Serial  EmpType       SAction
-------------------- ----------- ------------ -----------
10012845             2           5            940705
13395353             1           5            921113
13395353             3           2            941119
13395353             4           1            951214
10013597             1           5            890201
10013597             2           53           921003
```

i must compare every EmpId to each other to find first EmpId and if there Empid was equal to others get their emptype and get distict of all emptype in that group of empid that are equal to each other and get distincted row that has min Saction .i dont know how!!!!

Comment: Which SQL product are you using? Are you using sql-server or mysql as you had both of them tagged. They are very different products.

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? Please share the SQL you previously wrote to try and achieve this.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts i use microsoft sql server 2008 R2

Comment: @Larnu actually i new with creating sql queries .i can not find way to perform something suitable

Comment: So you've made no attempts? What functions have you looked at? Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, it's for help on specific coding problems when you've failed to resolve the issue yourself (by trying).

Comment: actually a made attempts but my code was too elementary.i couldn't understand what can i do to fix my code @zeki-gumus code help me to develop my need

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have created extra field to add your comments. I have applied two `UPDATE` to the comment field. First one to find first EmpId,EmpType,Saction combination.
Second one is same query but excluded the emptype from the first one.

```
--DROP TABLE #Temp
--GO
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(   EmpID       INT
    ,Serial      INT
    ,EmpType     INT 
    ,SAction        INT
    ,Comment        VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO #Temp(EmpID,Serial,EmpType,SAction)
VALUES
 (10012845, 2 , 5  , 940705)
,(10012845, 3 , 5  , 951218)
,(10012845, 4 , 5  , 960130)
,(10012845, 5 , 5  , 970419)
,(10012845, 6 , 5  , 970419)
,(13395353, 1 , 5  , 921113)
,(13395353, 2 , 5  , 931116)
,(13395353, 3 , 2  , 941119)
,(13395353, 4 , 1  , 951214)
,(13395353, 5 , 1  , 961713)
,(10013597, 1 , 5  , 890201)
,(10013597, 2 , 53 , 921003)
,(10013597, 3 , 53 , 960320)
,(10013597, 4 , 53 , 970419)
,(10013597, 5 , 53 , 970419)

UPDATE #Temp SET Comment = '** same empid and first EmpType and min SAction'
FROM (SELECT EmpID
            ,MIN(Serial)  Serial
            ,MIN(SAction)  Saction
        FROM #Temp 
        GROUP BY EmpID) S
WHERE #Temp.EmpID = S.EmpID
AND #Temp.Serial = S.Serial
AND #Temp.SAction = S.Saction

UPDATE #Temp SET Comment = '**same empid and different EmpType and min SAction'
FROM (SELECT T1.EmpID
            ,T1.EmpType
            ,MIN(T1.Serial) Serial
            ,MIN(T1.SAction)  Saction
        FROM #Temp T1
        GROUP BY T1.EmpID,T1.EmpType) S
WHERE #Temp.EmpID = S.EmpID
AND #Temp.Serial = S.Serial
AND #Temp.SAction = S.Saction
AND #Temp.Comment IS  NULL
--AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
--              FROM #Temp T2 
--              where #Temp.EmpID = t2.EmpID 
--              and T2.EmpType=#Temp.EmpType
--          )

select * from #Temp
```

Comment: thanks your code help me a lot and fix my problem @zeki-gumus